# StoryBoard iOS 5 - Custom UITableViewCell Crash Scrolling up

Tags: ios5, uitableview, storyboard

I have been coding a example of a UITableView with a custom UITableViewCell (PlayerCell). All work fine, I can see the elements in my table and I can select them, but when I do a scroll up, the app crash. I have reviewed the identifier, the class of the controller, everything, but when I use a custom cell, it not works. If I use a default style, it works fine, inclusive the scroll up.

I think I have the problem in this method: `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

But the debugger, don't show me an error, only something like: EXEC BAD ADRESSS (I don't have the computer here)

This is my code:

MyTeamViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyTeamViewController : UITableViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *players;

@end
```

MyTeamViewController.m

```
#import "MyTeamViewController.h"
#import "Player.h"
#import "PlayerCell.h"



@interface MyTeamViewController ()

@end

@implementation MyTeamViewController 
@synthesize players;
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    players = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:20];
    Player *player = [[Player alloc] init];
    player.name = @"Bill Evans";
    player.game = @"Tic-Tac-Toe";
    player.rating = 4;
    [players addObject:player];
    player = [[Player alloc] init];
    player.name = @"Oscar Peterson";
    player.game = @"Spin the Bottle";
    player.rating = 5;
    [players addObject:player];
    player = [[Player alloc] init];
    player.name = @"Dave Brubeck";
    player.game = @"Texas Hold’em Poker";
    player.rating = 2;
    [players addObject:player];



    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    //#warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    //#warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    NSUInteger numberCells = players.count;    

    return numberCells;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"PlayerCell";

    PlayerCell *cell = (PlayerCell *)[tableView
                                      dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];    

    if(cell == nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"Cell is NIL");
        //I don't know what put here <-- MY PROBLEM!!! :(

    }

    Player *player = [self.players objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.nameLabel.text = player.name;
    cell.pointsLabel.text = player.game;
    cell.clubImageView.image = [self 
                                imageForRating:player.rating];


    // Configure the cell...
    return cell;


}

- (UIImage *)imageForRating:(int)rating
{
    switch (rating)
    {
        case 1: return [UIImage imageNamed:@"1StarSmall.png"];
        case 2: return [UIImage imageNamed:@"2StarsSmall.png"];
        case 3: return [UIImage imageNamed:@"3StarsSmall.png"];
        case 4: return [UIImage imageNamed:@"4StarsSmall.png"];
        case 5: return [UIImage imageNamed:@"5StarsSmall.png"];
    }
    return nil;
}

/*
 // Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
 - (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
 // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
 return YES;
 }
 */

/*
 // Override to support editing the table view.
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
 if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
 // Delete the row from the data source
 [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
 }   
 else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
 // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
 }   
 }
 */

/*
 // Override to support rearranging the table view.
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
 {
 }
 */

/*
 // Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
 - (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
 // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
 return YES;
 }
 */

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
    /*
     <#DetailViewController#> *detailViewController = [[<#DetailViewController#> alloc] initWithNibName:@"<#Nib name#>" bundle:nil];
     // ...
     // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
     [detailViewController release];
     */
}

@end
```

The other files:

Player.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Player : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *game;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int rating;
@end
```

Player.m

```
#import "Player.h"

@implementation Player

@synthesize name;
@synthesize game;
@synthesize rating;
@end
```

PlayerCell.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface PlayerCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *nameLabel;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *pointsLabel;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIImageView 
*clubImageView;

@end
```

PlayerCell.m

```
#import "PlayerCell.h"

@implementation PlayerCell

@synthesize nameLabel;
@synthesize pointsLabel;
@synthesize clubImageView;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

@end
```

Thank you so much!!

**EDIT:** I solved it with: `players = [[NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:20] retain];`

Comment: The PlayerCell in the story board has corretly assigned the identifier and the class... :(

Comment: Ok, I'm going to try this tutorial: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Using_Xcode_Storyboards_to_Build_Dynamic_TableViews_with_Prototype_Table_View_Cells

Answer (score 0):

I would try to remove the

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
```

In the PlayerCell.m - u don't need them.

Comment: Ok' I'll try when I come home, thanks! I'll give you a feedback!